# Multiple Occurrences of an Event at the same Time

Tags: haskell, frp

Conal Elliott's paper defines Event as

```
type Event a = [(T , a)] -- for non-decreasing times
```

This would allow more than one occurrence at a time.
In my FRP library I would like to implement the function:

```
sample :: Reactive a -> Future () -> Future a
```

This would sample the reactive when the future fires. Since the reactive can have more than one value at the time the future fires how should I implement it? Always use the last, the first, or a nonempty list?

This is how the sample function should behave:

```
sample
    (MkReactive "a"
        (MkEvent
            (MkFuture 2
                (MkReactive "b" ...)
            )
        )
    (MkFuture 1 ())
= MkFuture 1 "a"
```

Comment: How do your Reactive & Future correspond to Event & Behavior as Conal defines them?

Comment: @bergey I am using Conal's definitions of Reactive, Event, and Future

Comment: Contrary to the close vote, this question is very much not "primarily opinion-based". In any case, for extra clarity I suggest linking to the paper by Conal you are using. (It looks like [*Push-pull functional reactive programming*](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/), but I'm only guessing.)

Comment: @duplode: Thank you for pointing out that this question is not a matter of opinion, since there is a precise specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper [Push-pull functional reactive programming](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/) (if duplode is correct), the fundamental sampling combinator `switcher` is described as:

> The semantics of *b₀ `switcher` e* chooses and samples either *b₀*
>   or the last behavior from *e* before a given sample time *t*

`sample` should behave the same way to be compatible with the combinators in that paper. Since a `Reactive` is an `Event` with an initial value, and a `Future` is a time-value pair, `sample r (MkFuture t ())` should return a `MkFuture t v` where `v` is the last value in `r` from strictly before `t`, or the initial value of `r` if there is no such value. There's no issue with multiple values at the same time: any values at time `t` are ignored since they're not strictly before `t`, and of the values before `t`, "take the last one" is unambiguous.

Comment: Do you know the reasoning behind that choice (switch using < rather than <=)?

Comment: @2426021684 The choice of `<` rather than `<=` is crucial for self-reactive behaviors and systems of mutually reactive behaviors to have values other than bottom (no information / nontermination) when sampled exactly at event occurrences.

Comment: @Conal how would one construct a self-reactive reactive or behavior?

Comment: @2426021684 With a predicate event, i.e., one that fires whenever a time-varying boolean becomes true. A behavior can thus react to a condition involving itself (directly or indirectly), causing the condition to become false.

Comment: The same situation occurs in a *purely* continuous setting (no events) in the form of ordinary differential equations (ODEs).